# Seleccionar fila de DataGridView con Enter y enviar registro a TextBox

Tags: visual-studio-2015

No logro seleccionar con la tecla Enter un registro del DataGridView para a su vez, poder enviarlo a cajas de texto.

Este proceso ya lo he hecho dando clic sobre la fila y no he tenido ningún problema; ahora que ocupo hacerlo dando Enter, simplemente no me funciona, no ocurre nada, el registro no se muestra en los Text Box.

Muestro mi código para que puedan decirme qué me falta.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.KeyDown
    Dim fila As Integer
    fila = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        e.SuppressKeyPress = True
        UsuariosAdmon.TextBox1.Text = Me.DataGridView1.Item(0, fila).Value
        UsuariosAdmon.TextEdit3.Text = Me.DataGridView1.Item(1, fila).Value
        Me.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

Este código lo tengo en el evento KeyDown del DataGrid.

Estoy usando VS 2015 Enterprise

Comment: debugueste el codigo? pasa por alli? toma los valores que corresponde?

Comment: Uso Visual Studio 2010 y el código antes mencionado corre a la perfección, por lo que el error no se encuentra en ese código.